# How to center a popup window exactly where I've clicked?

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a question on how I can change this code

```
selectedFeature = feature;
popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken", 
  feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
  null,
  div,
  null, null, onPopupClose);
feature.popup = popup;
```

to make the center point of popup window exactly where I've clicked, instead of on the center of object bounds as it is now ?

Answer (score 6):

I have a *not tested* proposition :

1 - From [that example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/click-handler.html) you will be able to get coordinates from click -see also [that example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/click.html).

2 - You will, then be able to convert coordinates to pixel, with [that function](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.5/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getPixelFromLonLat).

3 - Finally, you move the popup with *popup.[moveTo](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Popup-js.html#OpenLayers.Popup.moveTo)(new OpenLayers.Pixel(xxx));*.

You probably have to calculate it before, regarding popup width and height. With the help of jQuery it can even be dynamic.